# How do I skip an item in while loop if variable empty?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm trying to figure out how to skip printing a row from a MySQL table if the variable is empty. For instance, I have a table full of information. I have a while loop that echos the result. How can I skip an entry if a variable is empty?

For instance, can I cancel the echo if 'tweet1' is empty in the row?

```
mysql_connect ($DBsever, $DBusername, $DBpass) or die ('I cannot connect to the database becasue: '.mysql_error());
mysql_select_db ("$DBname");

$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM $DBtable ORDER BY time");

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
    echo "<br /><strong>".$row['time']." ".$row['headline']."</strong><br/>".$row['description']."<br />".$row['story1']." <a href=".$row['link1']." target='_blank'>".$row['link1']."</a> ".$row['tweet1']."<br />";}
```

Comment: use a condition and a `continue` to move on to the next iteration.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use `continue` control structure for skip an iteration. Please read the [docs](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.continue.php)

Example:

```
if(!$row['tweet']) {
  continue;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

```
if (empty($row['tweet'])) {
    continue;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

You could also not return rows without information in `tweet1`, this would make the php check for data in tweet1 unnecessary.

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM $DBtable WHERE tweet1 IS NOT NULL ORDER BY time");
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
if ($row['tweet1']) 
    echo "<br /><strong>".$row['time']." ".$row['headline']."</strong><br/>".$row['description']."<br />".$row['story1']." <a href=".$row['link1']." target='_blank'>".$row['link1']."</a> ".$row['tweet1']."<br />";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
  if (!empty($row['tweet1'])    {
    echo "<br /><strong>".$row['time']." ".$row['headline']."</strong><br/>".$row['description']."<br />".$row['story1']." <a href=".$row['link1']." target='_blank'>".$row['link1']."</a> ".$row['tweet1']."<br />";
  }
}
```